# how to achieve sorting along with pagination for my apache solr search results

Tags: php, drupal, solr

i have integrated the apache solr search module in drupal 7 and its working fine. 
I need some help on how to achieve sorting along with pagination for my apache solr search results.

I have Modified the schema.xml file to specify which are all the fields available for sorting. While indexing from my drupal's solr module i get list of all fields with sorting options.

So please guide me what will be my next step to achieve column wise sorting in my search results table.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add an index for the field(s) you want to sort on.  This will take a reindex for solr to take affect

```
function MY_MODULE_apachesolr_index_document_build_node(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type, $env_id) {
if(isset($entity->your_field['und'][0]['value'])){
    $your_field = $entity->your_field['und'][0]['value'];
    $document->addField('ss_your_field', $last_name);
}
```

}

Note that 'ss' here is the type of field solr recognises it as the first s being for string and the second being for 'single' as opposed to 'multiple'.  Only single fields can be sorted by.

Then alter the search queries to make the sort available and used like so:

```
function MY_MODULE_apachesolr_query_prepare(&$query){
    $query->setAvailableSort('ss_your_field', array('title' => t('Field Name'), 'default' => 'asc'));
    $query->setSolrSort('ss_your_field', 'asc');
}
```